# где моя ошибка, при пользования функции IF THEN ELSE в ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE tbl_registry 
SET CLM_CONCATANTE = 'в размере ' || ROUND(CLM_CONTRACT_ENDING_AMOUNT,2) || ' (' || NUMBER2WORD_RU(CLM_CONTRACT_ENDING_AMOUNT)  || ') сум '|| SUBSTR(ROUND(CLM_CONTRACT_ENDING_AMOUNT,2) -2, 2) ||' страхователю '
IF  CLM_CLIENT_TYPE='жисмоний' then  'п/к: ' || CLM_RETURN_CARDNUM else ' согласно расчету возврата страховой премии от' ||  CLM_ORDER_DATE || ' года' end
WHERE CLM_CONCATANTE IS NOT NULL
```

когда пишу код без

```
IF  CLM_CLIENT_TYPE='жисмоний' then  'п/к: ' || CLM_RETURN_CARDNUM else ' согласно расчету возврата страховой премии от' ||  CLM_ORDER_DATE || ' года' end
```

то работает без проблем, а когда его добавляю, не работает.

Comment: вам нужно использовать CASE WHEN ... вместо IF THEN , так как он не используется в SELECT

Comment: CASE  CLM_CLIENT_TYPE
when 'жисмоний' then  'п/к: ' || CLM_RETURN_CARDNUM 
else ' согласно расчету возврата страховой премии от' ||  CLM_ORDER_DATE || ' года' 
end так ?

Comment: Попробовать - быстрее, чем спросить и ждать ответа...

Comment: Error at line 4/0: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 847
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 833
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1903 такая ошибка ...

Comment: СРАБОТАЛО, спасибо всем